# Is it possible to exclude certain user views from ViewsLifeTime?

Tags: 2013, search, rest, search-api

I'm getting the most popular pages in our site collection using the search REST API:

```
_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x010100C568*'&sortlist='ViewsLifeTime:descending'
```

The problem is the results are skewed due to some developers/contributors looking at certain pages many times. Is it possible to exclude these users' views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not. The out of the box functionality has a single stack that throws any requests for that asset into the counter. You'd have to do some code to get what you're referring to either on server or client side.